# "Delphi Error" at auto generated code to consume SOAP WSDL

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

im using Delphi 10.3.2 Enterprise Edition.
I used Importer WSDL from Delphi and i get an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49asR.jpg)

The WSDL is: http://181.176.170.150:555//ConsultaRUCDNI.svc?wsdl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPglV.png)

Thanks for all help
Americo

Comment: i need to get the result fields in TEdit components

Comment: Are you able to create a mock service with this WSDL in SoapUI? Then I don't think there's any issue with the WSDL as such.

Comment: If possible, please include relevant source code directly in your question.

Comment: It is a bug ([RSP-21850](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21850)) in WSDL importer that was fixed in 10.4 Sydney.

Comment: Please do NOT post code as a picture. Instead post as text and use the `{}` button in the editor, after selecting the code, to format the text as code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
procedure Set_foto(Index : Integer; const ATArray<System.Byte>: TArray<System.Byte>);
```

is wrong. The correct one is:

```
procedure Set_foto(Index : Integer; const ATArray: TArray<System.Byte>);
```

And by the way, `TArray<System.Byte>` is `TBytes` so you can write this as well:

```
procedure Set_foto(Index : Integer; const ATArray: TBytes);
```

Comment: @americotorres If it works for you, you should mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.